# React dynamic inputs handle with in two input field without any use of button

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

create a new React component with 2 input fields, input1 and input2.
Users can type any number in either of these input fields. You need to ensure that (input2 minus input1) is
equal to 1 always. Means if user type value 5 in input1 then input2 value should change to 6
(to make input2 - input1 = 1). And similarly, if input2 value is 100 then input1 value should change to 99.
You need to just play around with input values.

Note :- In the UI only 2 input fields should be present. No button needed

I need help in the above question how to handle this change in input automatically when user make input in one input field.

Comment: You need to show your code and explain what do you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

```
export default function App() {
  const [input1data,setinput1data] = useState();
  const [input2data,setinput2data] = useState();
  const handleinput1 = (event) =>{
    setinput2data(Number(event.target.value) +1);
  };
  const handleinput2 = (event) =>{
    setinput1data(Number(event.target.value) - 1);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
     <input type="number" value={input1data} onChange={handleinput1}/>
     <input type="number" value={input2data} onChange={handleinput2}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).